# HTML element doesn't removes by jquery with name containing backslash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I'm trying to delete a DOM element, finding it by `data-value` property. And I have a problem when this property is containing a '\' symbol.
Example:

```
<li class="tag" data-value="test\image">
     <span>test\image</span>
     <input type="text" value="test\image">
     <i class="reset-clear-icon small"></i>
</li>
```

In my JS code, the element removing like this:

```
...
//passing tag selector here
$tag.remove();
...
```

Is there any approach to make the `remove()` method work for the data with backslashes?
And for data to show correct, without encoding `backslash` symbol in html like this

```
$tag.replace("\\", "&#92")
```

so it would display in html `test&#92image`.

Comment: $tag is a selector for `li.tag`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\\\\` instead `\` in your `JQuery` selector like this:

```js
$("li[data-value='test\\\\image']").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="tag" data-value="test\image">
     <span>test\image</span>
     <input type="text" value="test\image">
     <i class="reset-clear-icon small"></i>
</li>
```

*HTML page content must be empty.*

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
$(".tag").data([value="test\image"]).remove();
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dinker/b90d366z/)